# CakePHP - Web page try to load all the js files in the webroot

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have a big project using CakePHP. I have a web page and I only want it to load the js files in a subfolder of `webroot` but it seems like loading all the js files in the `webroot`

I want files in this directory

```
/webroot/js/signaturepad
```

and in my code I wrote:

```
echo $this->Html->script(array(
                '/js/signaturepad/TopazSignature',
                '/js/signaturepad/SigWebTablet'
            ), array('inline' => false));
```

So it supposes to read these two js files only while in the page source I can see tons of js files in the webroot been loaded. And my js functions are not working at all.

Comment: Be more specific. Where in the code are you writing this? Are there other inclusions in the layout file that will precede the code you have here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want files in this directory
>
> /webroot/js/signaturepad

start paths **without slash '/'** and 'js' folder name, like:

```
echo $this->Html->script(array(
         'subfolder/your_js_file_name_here',
         'subfolder/your_js_file_name_here.min'
     ), array('inline' => false));
```

This generate path like `example.com/js/subfolder/your_js_file_name_here.js`

If you want use other folder inside webroot folder, for example: 'frontend' then start path with slash '/'.

```
echo $this->Html->script(array(
         '/frontend/your_js_file_name_here',
         '/forntend/your_js_file_name_here.min'
     ), array('inline' => false));
```

This generate path like `example.com/frontend/your_js_file_name_here.js`